# Pattern matching in a Swift for loop

Tags: swift, pattern-matching

It seems like there should be a "Swiftier" way to do this - but I'm still wrapping my head around the various ways to do pattern matching in Swift.

Suppose I have an Array of AnyObject and I'd like to loop through it and if the item is an Int AND the Int is a multiple of 5, then I'd like to print it out.  Here's my initial approach that works:

```
let myStuff: [AnyObject] = [5, "dog", 11, 15, "cat"]

for item in myStuff {
    if let myInt = item as? Int where myInt % 5 == 0 {
        print ("\(item)")
    }
}
```

Honestly, that's not bad...but with all of Swift's pattern matching syntax, it seems like I should be able to consolidate the logic to 1 line.  So far, I haven't found an approach that works - but I was expecting to be able to do something like:

```
//This doesn't work, but I feel like something similar to this should
for item in myStuff where item is Int, item % 5 == 0 {
    print ("\(item)")
}
```

Obviously, this isn't a huge deal - but it's more a thought exercise for me to understand Swift's pattern matching a little better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can combine a [pattern matching conditional cast](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID425) with a `where` clause like so:

```
let myStuff: [AnyObject] = [5, "dog", 11, 15, "cat"]

// item will be an Int, and divisible by 5
for case let item as Int in myStuff where item % 5 == 0 {
    print(item)
}

// Prints:
// 5
// 15
```

Comment: Ah!  I was close in one of my attempts.  I had actually tried:  "case let item as? Int...".    That felt right to me since the syntax for an if statement is:  "if let item = something as? Int....".

Comment: @chrismc Yes, the syntax for conditional casting with optional binding (`if let ... as? ...`) indeed differs from the syntax for conditional casting with a pattern match. You could actually re-write that if-statement as `if case let item as Int = something`, although this is obviously less expressive than `if let item = something as? Int` (and therefore rarely seen). The reason they differ is that `as?` generates an optional, which the optional binding then unwraps – but the `as` type-casting pattern just attempts to type-cast, and is matched if this succeeds.

Answer (score 7):

[@Hamish's neat solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38923201/4573247) is, imho, the "optimal" one, and the one to be accepted. But for the sake of the discussion, as an alternative the somewhat same logic can be applied with a chained functional approach:

```
let myStuff: [AnyObject] = [5, "dog", 11, 15, "cat"]

myStuff.flatMap{ $0 as? Int }.filter{ $0 % 5 == 0}.forEach {
    print($0)
} /* 5 15 */
```

Comment: No problem @dfri :)