# Is it possible to immediately typecast a "foreach" element in swift for?

Tags: swift, for-loop, foreach, casting

So I have an array of AnyObject.

```
let arr : [AnyObject];
```

I want to iterate through the array.

```
for el in arr {
    let _el = el as! MyClass;
    // do something with _el
}
```

Can I do something to eliminate the typecasting and include it into the "foreach" statement? For example like:

```
for el: MyClass in arr {
    // do something with el
}
```

I know this is a noob question and maybe not so important. I just want to know if something like this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: See [Pattern matching in a Swift for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923156/pattern-matching-in-a-swift-for-loop) (perhaps a dupe target?) – in this case you can do `for case let el as MyClass in arr {...}`

Comment: @Hamish ooh okay, the terminology "pattern matching" and syntax "case" is the searching keyword I was looking for to research this further. Thanks!

Comment: @Hamish Since OP seems happy with the linked Q&A, I believe we should dupe mark it to that target.

Comment: @dfri Yup, I agree

Comment: @dfri yes, thanks! sometimes people just don't know what keyword to search for something. So I'm happy with this dupe mark feature thing!